# Power BI Create Line graph for Measures on same timeline starting at different time periods

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset in which I have the following columns:

| Case Number | Employee Name | Hire Date | DaysToClose | CasesStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 01/01/2020 | 10 | Closed |
| 2 | DEF | 01/01/2021 | 15 | Closed |
| 3 | Gh | 01/01/2019 | 12 | Closed |
| 4 | ABC | 01/01/2020 | 18 | Closed |
| 5 | DEF | 01/01/2021 | 1 | Closed |
| 6 | ABC | 01/01/2020 | 19 | Closed |
| 7 | ABC | 01/01/2020 | 1 | Closed |

I want to create a line graph to measure Avg DTC in each Quarter depending on when they were hired. For example, let's say 10 employees were hired in 2020 Q1, They took Avg X days to close in 2020 Q1, Y in 2020 Q2, and so forth.

In 2020 Q2 15 employees were hired, they took on avg Z days to close in Q2, and W DTC in 2020 Q3, and so forth.

In a nutshell, I want to compare the days to close off all the employees in each qtr based on when they were hired. Attached image below for the output I'm looking for.

I know I can solve this by creating multiple tables based on the hire date but looking for a better solution, I'm unable to use DatesinPeriod, Datesbetween function as HireDate has duplicates date values.

[image]

Comment: Power bi can do this automatically by ensuring you have your date as a datetime. It then creates a hierarchy so you can go to quarter level. In the setting for the value you can show averages..

Comment: @Aldert Hey the problem is not the date hierarchy, I know I can reach the quarter level. Please read my post again.